# How to Get select row data of gridview into dropdown list and textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have textbox controls and ddl in asp. Net form .. Through which i am saving data and showing it on grid view.. Now i have to update data by selecting specific row in gridview and selected data should be loaded into text boxes and ddls... How to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can use the codes below to get index of the selected column if required:

```
int columnIndex = dataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
int rowIndex = dataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
```

SelectionChanged function can be used to detect any user selection and you can set the values to your textbox and ddl inside the function:

```
 private void gridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (gridView.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                int age = Convert.ToInt32(gridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Age"].Value.ToString());
                string name = gridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Name"].Value.ToString();

                txtName.Text = name;
                ddlAgeList.Items.Insert(0,new ListItem(age.ToString()));// 0 is index of item
            }
        }
```

ClickEvent function is also an alternative, see below:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        txtName.Text = row.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString();
        var age = row.Cells["Age"].Value.ToString();
        ddlAgeList.Items.Insert(0,new ListItem(age));// 0 is index of item 
    }
}
```

Comment: But the problem is i want all the values in ddl and selected one should be the one in the grid view